# Random sample from Normal Distribution, why isn't the variance divided by n?

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling

Below is a question containing parts b) and c). Further below is the mark scheme.

In part c) they take a random sample from T, which is normally distributed. I was expecting the distribution to change, so the variance is now divided by n. However, the mark scheme does not reflect this anywhere.

Why doesn't the answer to part c) reflect the variance being divide by n, given it is a random sample?

**Question:**

[image]

**Mark scheme:**

[image]

Comment: I think you're misusing the CLT here, the "divided by $\sqrt{n}$" bit refers specifically to the distribution of the sample means of the samples, which isn't relevant to this problem. Here they're just using the properties of mean and variance on sums and scalar multiples.

Comment: You do not calculate the variance of the **mean**, which is $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$